# Swift - Calling initializer, missing argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am use Swift to call an initializer from objective-c class(JSONModel)

The class contains some initializer:

```
  -(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString*)string error:(JSONModelError**)err;
  -(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(JSONModelError**)err;
  -(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict error:(NSError **)err;
  -(instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error;
```

Since I want to call the initWithDictionary one, I write code like

```
var error:NSError
```

`var loginRes = RegisterResponse(dictionary: dict , error: &error`)

in which , RegisterResponse is a subclass of JSONModel, dict is a pre-used Dictionary variable

However, the complier complains like:
 missing argument for parameter "usingEncoding" in call.

It seems that the complier think I am calling the

```
  -(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string usingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding error:(JSONModelError**)err;
```

rather than the third one. Are there any solution?

Comment: Try `var error:NSError?`

Comment: Deleted my answer as I though you were using the 1st initializer. @MartinR's comment should be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 -(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict error:(NSError **)err;
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
 init!(dictionary dict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error err: NSErrorPointer)
```

As explained in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns / Error Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_5),
you have to pass an *optional* `NSError` as an in-out expression:

```
var error : NSError?
let loginRes = RegisterResponse(dictionary: dict, error: &error)
```

or with error checking:

```
var error : NSError?
if let loginRes = RegisterResponse(dictionary: dict, error: &error) {
    println("success")
} else {
    println(error!.localizedDescription)
}
```